# the comments of posts or video does not return data from page facebook

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm utilizing Meta Developer Tools to test an API, but I'm encountering an issue where I'm not receiving any comments, posts, videos, or attachments. Interestingly, I successfully used the same endpoint last week and received the expected data. I'm unsure why this isn't working anymore. Here's the endpoint I'm using:

me?fields=posts{message,created_time,id,comments{message,id,from,created_time},attachments{media_type,subattachments},status_type},videos{description,title,source,id,created_time}

[image: response on meta developper too]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the data with the same endpoint:-

```
me?fields=posts{message,created_time,id,comments{message,id,from,created_time},attachments{media_type,subattachments},status_type},videos{description,title,source,id,created_time}
```

Make sure you select the page in **Page Access Tokens** in the **"User or Page"** dropdown.

Permission scope used:
`pages_show_list`, `business_management`, `pages_read_engagement`, `pages_manage_metadata`, `pages_read_user_content`, `pages_manage_ads`, `pages_manage_posts`, `pages_manage_engagement`

I hope this helps.

EDIT:
I added the `access_token` explicitly in the query parameter but it also works without adding it to the query parameter(as the tool does it for you when you make request, you check this in the cURL command by clicking on "</> Get Code").

[image]

Comment: Could you please test the endpoint to see if it returns both comments and videos? I have added all the necessary permission scopes, but I haven't noticed any changes. I'm unable to figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: @iyedghodhbane Yes, it is returning posts, attachments, videos, and comments. Whatever you specify in the query parameter it returns.

Comment: @iyedghodhbane, what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: I created a page featuring multiple posts and comments, but unfortunately, when I attempted to use the comments endpoint, no results were returned.

Comment: @iyedghodhbane When you use `me?fields` what it returns?

Comment: I believe the issue with the app at meta developer tool since I had created another one using the same page, endpoint, and permission scope, and now it is functioning properly.

Comment: retrun page_id and name

Comment: @iyedghodhbane No I meant with full url: `me?fields=posts{message,created_time,id,comments{message,id,from,created_time},attachments{media_type,subattachments},status_type},videos{description,title,source,id,created_time}`

Comment: Anyway, you got it working :)

Comment: Now with the new app in the meta it brings everything back